# Force secure SQL Server connection from client application

Tags: .net, sql, winforms, security

[EDITED]

I am connecting to SQL Server 2005. i have configured the certificate on the server and have been able to force encryption form the server successfully.

The problem is that i cannot use forced encryption from the server because that breaks another system. So we need to force encryption from the client side.

how do i  connect to the server using secure connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [Encrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.encrypt.aspx) property to True in the connection string builder. Or add [`Encrypt=Yes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) on the connection string, but using a connection string builder is so much better.

This is also described in the [SQL Protocols team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/04/476705.aspx):

> For a per-connection basis, the
>   encryption option can be specified in
>   the connection string.  E.g., using
>   the `"Encrypt=yes"` keyword as a
>   connection attribute.

Comment: it just timeout after 3600 seconds

Answer (score 0):

How about [using SSL to encrypt the connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649255.aspx)?